# Input from the use in a try/except block

Tags: python, input, try-catch

1. List item

i want to let the user type 1 , 2 or quit otherwise i want to put him to type again one of them. everything works with 1 and 2 but for quit doesn't work, and i also want if he types quit to use sys.exit('message') - this part is from a function where u can choose your difficulty level. also its a hangman game. tanks

Sloved!!

import sys
while True:
difficulty = input("Choose difficulty 1 for easy 2 for hard: ").lower()
try:

```
         if difficulty == '1':
            print('Easy game mode is set!')
         elif difficulty =='2':
            print('Hard game mode is set!')
         elif difficulty =='quit':
            print('Sheeeeeeeeeeeeeeesh')

      except:
         continue
      if difficulty == '1' or difficulty =='2':
         break
      elif difficulty == 'quit':
         sys.exit('byeeeee')
         break
    #elif difficulty 
      else:
         print('invalid ')
```

Comment: What is the problem? Of course "quit" doesn't exit the program because you never call `sys.exit`. Also what is the point of the `except ValueError` - the code will never produce a value error? Maybe you meant `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the user input in uppercase for difficulty variable.
And in if condition verifying in lowercase.
So remove the `upper()` from
`input("Choose difficulty 1 for easy 2 for hard: ").upper()`

Comment: you are a king. tanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`try:` and `except:` is probably not what you want to use here because you won't get a `ValueError` and thus the except does not execute. Maybe try something like:

```
while True:
    difficulty = input("Choose difficulty 1 for easy 2 for hard: ").upper()
    if difficulty == '1':
        print('Easy game mode is set!')
        break
    elif difficulty =='2':
        print('Hard game mode is set!')
        break
    elif difficulty =='QUIT':
        print('bye')
        break
    else:
        print("you can only choose 1, 2, or quit.")
```

It breaks the loop when the correct input is given, and keeps looping otherwise.

If you would LIKE to have a ValueError when they enter a wrong input you can use `raise` like so:

```
while True:
    difficulty = input("Choose difficulty 1 for easy 2 for hard: ").upper()
    if difficulty == '1':
        print('Easy game mode is set!')
        break
    elif difficulty =='2':
        print('Hard game mode is set!')
        break
    elif difficulty =='QUIT':
        print('bye')
        break
    else:
        print("you can only choose 1, 2, or quit.")
        raise ValueError #notice the additional line here
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the part with sys.exit() i tried to introduce it in the try block after difficulty == 'quit' sys.exit('bye') but it did not work. your code works but if i type something else then 1 , 2 or quit it will give me raise ValueError and not the posibility to try again for an input

Comment: @GeorgeAnghel114 the first version does not raise the value error. As I mentioned it depends on which behavior you want. the first option loops and lets you try again.

Comment: i got it now, tanks a lot. the biggest problem was the upper() and how i wrote 'quit' with upper or lower . tanks, you helped me a lot !

Comment: Yes, fixing that was your error, but using `except:` also does not make sense in your example because `ValueError` cannot occur with the code you had.

Comment: but if i delete that part i ll have errors again, if i let only the except: print() continue and the rest remain the same is still ok right?